# How to calculate nth business day of a month?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, calendar, python-dateutil

How to calculate 3rd, 5th etc business day of a month excluding U.S holidays using python?

```
import calendar
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

cal = calendar.Calendar()

working_days = len([x for x in cal.itermonthdays2(now.year, now.month) if x[0] !=0 and x[1] < 5])

print("Total working days this month: " + str(working_days)
```

This returns the number of working days but I need that to check if an entered date is 3rd or 5th or nth business day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the necessary import:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
```

Then create a custom calendar based on US holidays:

```
usb = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar = USFederalHolidayCalendar())
```

To find n-th business day, e.g. in July 2023, start with defining the last day before
the month in question:

```
ts = pd.Timestamp(2023, 6, 30)
```

And to find e.g. the third business day in this month, run:

```
ts + 3 * usb
```

getting `Timestamp('2023-07-06 00:00:00')`.

But if you want to find **all** business days in a particular range, run
e.g.:

```
pd.date_range('2023-07-01', '2023-07-15', freq=usb)
```

getting:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-07-03', '2023-07-05', '2023-07-06', '2023-07-07',
               '2023-07-10', '2023-07-11', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13',
               '2023-07-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```

As you can see, this list doesn't include e.g. *2023-07-04*, the US Independence Day.